# tiny_serial driver example from LDD

Tags: linux, device-driver

I have compiled and installed the tiny_serial driver example from [the book *Linux Device Drivers* by Greg Kroah-Hartman](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/linux-device-drivers/0596005903/ch18.html).  I use the sources from https://github.com/duxing2007/ldd3-examples-3.x.git

The device node `/dev/ttytiny0` is successfully created but I am having trouble reading anything from the device. Looking at the driver, it seems that I should be able to read a *'t'* character.

Running `stty` gets me the following below error:

```
root@brijesh-M11BB:~/ldd3-examples-3.x# setserial /dev/ttytiny0
/dev/ttytiny0, UART: unknown, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 0

root@brijesh-M11BB:~/ldd3-examples-3.x# stty -F /dev/ttytiny0
stty: /dev/ttytiny0: Input/output error
```

Similarly doing `cat /dev/tinytty0` also reports a similar error. I also tried `minicom -D /dev/ttytiny0` but the device is always shown as offline.

It seems I am missing something, can anyone please point out what I am missing?

This is happening with me on both Ubuntu 15.10 (3.19.x kernel) and older 2.6.28 kernel.

Comment: The [edit] link is just below your question, on the left.  I have updated the question with this information.

Answer (score 0):

I have debugged it and found the root cause.

strace shows -EIO on tinytty0 device. -EIO was generated from driver tty layer (-ENO_TTY_DEVICE). The reason for ENO_TTY_DEVICE was port->type is set to 0 (i.e unknown).  Setting the port->type = PORT_16550A before adding uart driver resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

While the previous answer was correct, it did not explain where to fix the code.

Note: I am using linux kernel 3.10

I implemented the one-line fix in the declaration of the uart_port struct, here is how:

```
static struct uart_port tiny_port = {
    .ops        = &tiny_ops,
    .type       = PORT_16550A, // THIS IS THE FIX
};
```

I believe this may be a bug in the kernel code, because by not setting the uart_port type, it defaults to PORT_UNKNOWN.

While I understand this may be a protection, it seems more correct to leave it at PORT_UNKNOWN rather than that of another random device.

### BONUS POINTS:

After fixing the PORT_UNKNOWN issue, if you get a kernel panic for dividing by 0, comment out the following lines from duxing2007's code:

```
baud = uart_get_baud_rate(port, new, old, 0, port->uartclk/16);
quot = uart_get_divisor(port, baud);
```

### BONUS POINTS 2:

[This link](https://lkml.org/lkml/2008/8/5/295) shows how a developer with a similar issue (Ira Snyder) implemented the tiny_exit() function, so that you can remove the kernel module without causing a hang.